# Odoo v13: how to access quotation template html code

Tags: odoo-13, quotations

I am using Odoo v13 CE:

I can not find the online quotation template html code under Customise Theme > HTML/CSS/JS Editor.
Also not under Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views.

Can someone help me to right direction.

Comment: Search for quotation under `Technical/Actions/Reports` and select one record in the list view then click on QWeb views button on the top right to see the different templates related to selected report.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "thanks" or similar in questions. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it for more information.

Comment: I checked all the reports but my copy of the online quotation template is not under any QWeb view of the Technical/Actions/Reports.